# Performance of drawing function

Tags: c++, performance, function, arguments, real-time

I'm creating small engine/framework for making games. It's kind of simple question but I haven't found an answer so I'd like to consult you.

There are some `class`es derived from `Graphic` with the `Draw(...)` function. `Draw()` will be called dozens or maybe even hundreds of times (if there are many sprites to render). `Draw()` is too big to be inline (10-20 lines).

1. I'd like it to be `virtual` (sometimes but rather rarely I'll be using polymorphism*). I think it shouldn't affect greatly on performance but do you think it should be `virtual`?
2. Should it have some arguments (2-6) describing position to render (etc)? I don't have an idea if passing many arguments will make it slower. Maybe every drawable object should have its own position/area data?

The most important question is 2.

*ex. with animations

Comment: Belongs on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Belongs to `use a profiler before thinking of optimization`. Also, calling a function a couple of hundred times should have absolutely no impact.

Comment: @DeadMG: You're right but I meant rather real-time programming.

Comment: @tibur: I'll be thinking of omptimization at the end but the question is important for whole project so I have to know it at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any object which needs to be drawn will be affecting a large number of pixels; it is likely that drawing itself will take *much* more time than calling the drawing function, so the calling overhead will be negligible. Don't worry about it until profiling shows it to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Ok. Now I'm going to make some decisions more easily.

Comment: Right. Think in terms of percentages.

Answer (score 0):

First you should choose in-memory, double-buffer drawing using `BitBlt`, `StretchBlt` functions.

- If the base class declares virtual as pure-virtual, isn't a performance problem at all.
- Yes, passing multiple arguments can make it slow - put them into structure, and pass reference/pointer of that structure; or use a shared area (private variables in class).
- Yes, for redrawing (re-painting) would need all data related to object - that's obvious!